# Start new activity android app dev

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new in android development. I have been trying to start a new activity after pressing an image button. But when I try to run it in the emulator I always get an error: "*AppName* has stopped".

Here is my code:
Image button:

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/FirstAidButton"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/BodyMassIndex"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/firstaid"
        android:src="@drawable/firstaid" 
        android:onClick="fatTutorial" />
```

Java:

```
public void fatTutorial(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstAidTutorial.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="dr.droid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/drdroid"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   <activity android:label="@string/title_text" android:name="dr.droid.FirstAidTutorial"/>

   </application>

</manifest>
```

Receiving class(FirstAidTutorial):

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }
```

LogCat:

```
   08-20 18:13:28.428: E/Trace(633): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-20 18:13:28.898: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 4% free 8140K/8455K, paused 66ms, total 71ms
08-20 18:13:29.008: D/dalvikvm(633): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 194K, 5% free 8254K/8647K, paused 40ms, total 41ms
08-20 18:13:29.619: I/Choreographer(633): Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-20 18:13:29.738: D/gralloc_goldfish(633): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-20 18:13:32.068: D/AndroidRuntime(633): Shutting down VM
08-20 18:13:32.098: W/dalvikvm(633): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dr.droid/dr.droid.FirstAidTutorial}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at dr.droid.FirstAidTutorial.onCreate(FirstAidTutorial.java:13)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  ... 11 more
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  ... 24 more
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060000 a=-1 r=0x7f060000}
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2035)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:342)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:772)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:442)
08-20 18:13:32.388: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  ... 27 more
```

firstaidtutorial.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AnimalBite"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/animalbite"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textColorHint="@style/AppTheme"
        android:textSize="25dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ChokingInfant"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/chokinginfant"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ChokingChild"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/chokingchild"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ChokingAdult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/chokingadult"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Convulsion"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/convulsion"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CPRAdult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cpradult"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CPRInfant"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cprinfants"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HeimlichManeuver"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/heimlichmaneuver"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MinorBurn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/minorburn"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MinorCut"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/minorcut"
        android:padding="5dp"   
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas? And also, how can I create an xml for that new activity so I can put designs/layouts to it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you added your FirstAidTutorial class into the manifest file? If yes, please post your log errors that we can check what is wrong with your code.

Comment: The code is not complete, I can't take any conclusions with that...but anyway, the ultimate conclusion you would get from the LogCat console. Open the LogCat console on your IDE and run the app again and it will most certainly indicate what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare `FirstAidTutorial` Activity in manifest file .

```
<activity android:label="@string/title_text" android:name=".FirstAidTutorial"/>
```

> how can I create an xml for that new activity so I can put designs/layouts to it.

First create one xml file in res -> layout folder then set that file in FirstAidTutorial Activity using `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);`.

```
public class FirstAidTutorial extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

    }
}
```

Comment: Ooops. forgot to include that. already declared it to manifest. see my edited post. still got the same error.

Comment: Declare like this . <activity android:label="@string/title_text" android:name=".FirstAidTutorial"/>

Comment: you forgot to put DOT(.) before activity name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15556/discussion-between-ljpv14-and-chirag-raval)

Comment: use package name.activity name in manifest file instead of .(DOT)

Comment: have you add super.onCreate() in Home Activity

Comment: Finally, I forgot to include that. Thanks!

Comment: I have an issue. Whenever I'm adding this line: setContentView(R.layout.activity_firstaidtutorial); The app will always stop after clicking the button. But when I remove the layout, the next activity starts. Any ideas?

Comment: There is problem in your layout file .

Answer (score 0):

declare FirstAidTutorial in the manifest like this. your package should start with a "com."

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dr.droid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
android:icon="@drawable/drdroid"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


 <activity
    android:name=".Home"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".FirstAidTutorial"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

   </application>
```